# Custom Urls In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am working on a new app in rails. I have already set up a `user` model using Devise and a `post` model and controller. What I want to be able to do is have a url like:

```
www.site.com/user/post
```

Which will show the `post` layout for that specific `user`. I am already using `friendly_id` in order to use the title and username for the user and title id's.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you mean post layout for a specific user right?

Comment: So you are looking for a route like `get '/:user_id/:id', to: 'posts#show', as: :post`? If not please clarify your question a bit so we can understand what you are looking for because this should suffice for `www.site.com/username/title-of-my-post` when using `friendly_id`

Comment: Well basically right now I have to write **www.site.com/posts/post_id** in order to view a post. Instead i want to be able to write **www.site.com/user_id/post_id** in order to view it

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. I just did what you said and it works. When I tried it earlier it didn't seem to work because i had some code to allow upvoteing and I had to put your code above the code i had.

Comment: @ZSOR glad it worked but that sounds like you possibly have some routing collisions. Might want to make sure you're not overwriting routes for other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `routes.rb` file (after your `devise_for` line):

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/user/post", to: "posts#show"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your models are like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end
```

You can use something like this in your routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
   resources :posts
end
```

This will give you possibility to have links like you want and you will be able to load which template you want.

Comment: Actually, this will create routes like `/users/:user_id/posts/:id`

Comment: Yeah if i can remove the /users and /posts from these url that is exactly it :D